# Number of smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}$ (not up to diffeomorphism)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

On page 53 of Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 1*, Exercise 2-4 asks

> How many distinct $C^\infty$ structures are there on $\mathbb{R}$?
>   (There is only one up to diffeomorphism; that is not the question
>   being asked.)

Is he just looking for the fact that there are infinitely many such structures, because the maximal atlases containing $x^{1/n}$ for $n$ odd are distinct? Or is there something more to say?

Comment: He's saying that if $X$, a smooth manifold, is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual structure), then it's actually diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual structure).

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I don't agree. I (mostly) agree with Eric's interpretation.

Comment: He's probably asking for a cardinality, not just "infinite".

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh, oops, didn't read the parenthetical question. Then, yeah, I assume he's just asking for the cardinality of the subset of the power set of an atlas which covers $\mathbb{R}$??

Comment: (And one can provide an actual cardinality here, except maybe for the usual set theoretic stuff I assume without thinking.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh, OK, I think there should be $|\mathbb{R}|$ many, because the maximal atlases compatible with $\begin{cases}e^{-r/x^2} & x >0\\ -e^{-r/x^2} & x <0 \\ 0 & x =0 \end{cases}$ should all be distinct for $r > 0$.

Comment: @EricAuld: Seems reasonable. I was going for $x \mapsto x^s$ for all $s>0$. You can probably do something similar to both our answers to get $|\Bbb R|$ many for any smoothable manifold $M$. One also has to bound the cardinality from above but this isn't too hard because you always have a countable atlas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can get $|\mathbb R|$-many structures by $x \mapsto x|x|^s$, $s>0$. We want to show that this is as many as one can get. For every differential structure can be defined by a countable atlas; there are only $|\mathbb R|$-many open sets on $\mathbb R$; and there are only $|\mathbb R|$-many homeomorphisms $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (they're all determined by where they send a countable dense subset). This proves the desired theorem.

This is actually true on any smoothable manifold, by roughly the same arguments.

Comment: @EricAuld: I think my latest function doesn't require me to work piecewise.

Comment: For someone who may read this later: in showing that there are $|\mathbb{R}|$ continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, as Mike said it is determined by its values on $|\mathbb{N}|$ many rationals, and (as stated in another problem on Stack somewhere) that $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| = |[0,1]^\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{R}|$ as follows: given a sequence of real numbers between zero and one $.a_1a_2..., .b_1b_2..., .c_1c_2...$, we can encode it into a single real number by $.a_1a_2b_1a_3b_2c_1...$